# Is it possible to create a choropleth map solely from a set of long/lat coordinates?

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, google-fusion-tables, geomap, choropleth

I'd like to visualize a number of points on a map. Unfortunately, there is no consistent address associated with each one. I've used Google Fusion tables to get a rough read on where the points are, and am relatively satisfied with the approximate locations of most points (sometimes Google figures out where they're located based on a landmark, sometimes based on an intersection provided, sometimes by street address, etc.).

My goal, then, is to create a choropleth map of a city (NYC, in this case), showing the number of points located in each neighbourhood. Is it possible to do this by somehow counting the number of points that fall within each neighbourhood?

I suspect that if fusion tables give me a passable visual, I may be able to use google's geocoding service in the same manner to figure out the number of points in each area, and use this to then build a choropleth (not a heat map — I'm after some level of interaction, like tooltips over each neighbourhood).

Is there any way to do this, or am I way, way off?